# Python script to insert in sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting some data through user input and then I have to insert the same data in sqlite tables.

```
conn = sqlite.connect('c:/sqlite/test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("Select Max(person_id) from persons")
person_id =c.fetchone()[0]

person_name = input ("Please provide User Name: ")
user_id= input("Please user_id table: ")
home_floor = input ("Please provide home floor for user: ")
start_dt= input("Please enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd) for User : ")
end_dt = input ("Please enter end date (yyyy-mm-dd) for User: ")

c.execute('insert into Person values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) person_id,person_name,user_id,home_floor,start_dt,end_dt)
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this instead -

```
c.execute("insert into Person values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (person_id,person_name,user_id,home_floor,start_dt,end_dt))
```

Also, after insert do not forget to `commit()`. In your case it should be -

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Stil I am getting `Error  near "%": syntax error`

Comment: @newbie, But the code I provided, there is no `%`. Change your last line with mine

Comment: thanks it worked, error was for some other lne :-(